# Access MKAnnotationView from mapView.annotations

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

Trying to animate my custom pin image.

However I cannot find a way to access the MKAnnotationView.

This task is trivial for example when you use

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {

}
```

As you have the view right there.

But I want to be able to animate a set of pin the I have zoomed into the area of.

Using the built in mapView property of annotations I can obtain the pins I require.

So within

```
    func findThePins(searchName:String) {

    var foundItems = [Client]()

    for aPin in mapView.annotations as! [Client] {

        if aPin.clientName.uppercaseString.rangeOfString(searchName.uppercaseString) != nil {
            foundItems.append(aPin)
        }
    }

    if !foundItems.isEmpty {
        println("move map - \(foundItems.count)")
        // moves to show the area of the screen containing the pins
        mapView.showAnnotations(foundItems, animated: true)
        // How to animate those pins in foundItems
    }
}
```

How can I access the view so I can then animate. I have a feeling Im going bout this the wrong way.

Example animation that would work fine in the `didSelectAnnotationView`

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
pinView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)
}, completion: { (completed) -> Void in
pinView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
})
```

Thanks

Comment: When you want to animate the pin/add the view ? On tap of any pin ? or you want to animate all the pins ?

Comment: To keep it simple a button action will be fine, for example I have 10 pins on the map already added. I want to at any stage highlight those that have a certain property (i.e. isOffice). So I was thinking I could just loop through all the maps annotations and the ones with that bool property i can animate. But I cannot figure out how to find the View associated with the pin from with in that loop.

Comment: So e.g if there are two categories A(isOffice) and B.There are 10 pins on the mapview and 6 belongs to A and 4 belongs to B.There will be two buttons as well A and B.When you press button A,6 pins from category A will have shown and other 4 pins of category B are hidden.Now you can apply animation effect of the pins that are currently showing.that's what you want if yes i have a solution for you.

Comment: You actually have difficulty in differentiating between pins of different categories ?

Comment: One button, that filters the pins, be there 50 or 1. It will loop through using the mapView.annotations. A simple if condition will be used to decide what pins I want to animate. But I cannot access the annotationView (dont know how) from within that loop. I have my data objects - i just have no association to the actual pin (view) on the map from within that loop.

Comment: Could you add some code

Comment: Thats the thing, how to I access an MKAnnotationView from within this loop. for aPin in mapView.annotations as! [MyCustomPin] {
  // need the view here
} I'm pretty sure its not possible.

Comment: Check out the map part in this video.https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1pqesu2pQQ3TlltQWNFUGd1SGc
First of all the pins are showing and on the selection of button respective pins that belongs to that particular category are showing.So after showing particular pins you want the animation to apply ?

Comment: Yes, but I will have 2 different kinds of pins - both showing on map at same time. I want only one type to animate. So i loop through the pins, if the pin for example is of kind X, it will animate, if its kind Z, it will not. Like highlighting those that meet my special condition. Rather than add pins of a condition (which is easy) I want to animate a sub set of an already added group of pins.

Comment: Add a sample code i will help if i can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved!

```
let clientAnnotation = self.mapView.viewForAnnotation(client)
```